# what datatype(id in objective c) to be returned when I have to set parameters of the method by using self and return self in the method in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

the method that am using is to set the url using a method .. and it returns self .. my question is what type of data to be declared if i'm going to return self in the definition in swift .. i used id in objective c . here's my objective c method..

```
- (id) initWithRequest:(NSString*)name serverport:(NSString*)port serverurl:(NSString*)url serverdata:(NSData*)data method:(Method )meth {

    //initialize all the fields of the httprequest object
    self.serverName = name;
    self.serverPort = port;
    self.serverURL = url;
    self.serverData = data;
    self.method = meth;
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift you can use `AnyObject` as the return type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add return type in the constructor in swift